# Problem using Mex

Tags: .net, wcf

My application uses both NetTcpBinding and BasicHttpBinding but each of them will expose a subset of my service class. I have created the service as below.

The problem is that even though I just added 3 of my contracts to the Mex binding, all of the contracts are shown when I want to add the service to my project.

```
m_ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Services), baseAddresses); 

BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(); 
basicHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false; 

m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof( IMyFirstService), basicHttpBinding, "MyFirstService"); 
m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMySecondService), basicHttpBinding, "MySecondService"); 
m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyThirdService), basicHttpBinding, "MyThirdService"); 

NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(); 
netTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647; 
netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647; 

m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyFirstService), netTcpBinding, "MyFirstService"); 
m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMySecondService), netTcpBinding, "MySecondService"); 
m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyFourthService), netTcpBinding, "MyFourthService"); 
m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyFifthService), netTcpBinding, "MyFifthService"); 
m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMySixService), netTcpBinding, "MySixService"); 


HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement(); 
httpTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647; 
httpTransport.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647; 

TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(); 
textMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647; 
textMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647; 
textMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647; 
textMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647; 
textMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;               

System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding mexHttpCustomBinding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(textMessageEncoding, httpTransport); 
mexHttpCustomBinding.Name = "MexHttpBindingConfig"; 
               m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(System.ServiceModel.Description.IMetadataExchange), mexHttpCustomBinding, "mex"); 

m_ServiceHost.Open();
```

Comment: Done.  Original question simply linked to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/0fe0e548-2063-4cb0-b216-03d19afd9f09 .

Comment: @Adam: Nicely done. I ran out of patience too quickly this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way you can accomplish this is to create two separate service hosts. One for the services to be exposed via http, and one for those exposed via net.tcp binding.